# Some question on the separable extension.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Let $E/F$ be a separable extension.

If $|F(\alpha):F|\le n$ for every $\alpha \in E$, show that $E/F$ is a finite extension and $|E:F|\le n$.

I know it can be easily proved using primitive element theorem. But I want to prove this without using that theorem.

Comment: have you found a solution to this?

Comment: Nope. But my original purpose for this question has been achived. I was considering how to prove P.E.T (Primitive element theorem) without using the Galois Theory and this question arises in that context. But I found that there is a way to prove P.E.T using only the injectivity of Galois correspondence which is much easier part compared to surjectivity part.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2633399/279515

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wouldn't proving this prove the 'primitive element theorem'?

You say $[F(\alpha):F] \leq n $ $\forall \alpha \in E$

But if $m = max\{[F(\alpha):F] | \alpha \in E\}$ then $m \leq n$ and your theorem applies to $m$ as well.

Now, $m = [F(\alpha_j):F]$ and we have $[E:F] = [E:F(\alpha_j)][F(\alpha_j):F] = [E:F(\alpha_j)]m \leq m$ implying $E = F(\alpha_j)$

Then the two theorems are equivalent.

I know this isn't a direct answer to your question but if the two are equivalent then the proof for one is good for the other, and most likely there isn't an easier proof then the one for the primitive element theorem (and this was too long for a comment)

** $m$ is well defined since the extension is algebraic by assumption.

Hope I didn't make a mistake in my reasoning.

Comment: I think the assumption the extension is algebraic is correct, and then I think the above is just fine. +1

Comment: @Mariah, Thanks. You are right! Two propositions are equivalent.