# L:K algebraic and separable then [L:K] $\leq$ n

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Suppose that $L:K$ is an algebraic and separable extension, and that for every $\alpha \in L$, the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ has degree at most $n$. Then $[L:K]\leq n$.

I'm having trouble proving this. The material that I am studying uses the following definition of separable:

Separable: an irreducible polynomial $f \in K[t]$ is separable over $K$ if is has no repeated roots in the algebraic closure of K. An algebraic extension $L:K$ is separable if every $\alpha \in L$ is algebraic over $K$ and the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K$ is separable over $K$.

I think this is to do with the primitive element theorem or perhaps the Tower Law, but I can't puzzle it out. Any help appreciated.

Comment: It is indeed a simple consequence of the primitive element theorem.  Suppose $[L:K]>n$ and get yourself a finite $M\leq L$ with $[M:K]>n$, etc.

Comment: See my answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2633399/279515. Just replace $E_s$ by $L$ and $k$ by $K$, in your notation.